# What is meant by a persistent installation of a server or a program inside a docker container?

Tags: docker

While reading the installation steps for the [GenePattern](https://genepattern.org) server in, I encountered the following line in the subsection "Overview of running GenePattern Server in Docker" of the section [Running GenePattern in a Docker container](https://genepattern.org/administrators-guide#docker):

> When running GenePattern Server from a docker container, it is assumed that this is desired to be a persistent GenePattern installation.  Therefore the details of jobs run and analysis output files are kept external to the docker container.

What is meant by a persistent installation of a server or a program inside a docker container?

Comment: When you mount the data volume. So when you remake your docker container, it doesn't lose the data. Persistent means, stored permanently across restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to say non-[ephemeral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemeral); you want your data maintained across container restarts, and therefore you would want to mount a Docker volume(s) where the server data is stored.